# Java compiler integer bug

Tags: java

I have this code that appeared in a quiz

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    class b {
      int i = 32;
      b() { b(); }
      void b() { System.out.println(++i); }
    }

    class d extends b {
      int i = 8;
      d() {}
      void b() { System.out.println(--i); }
    }

    b b = new d();
  }
}
```

What should be the output? It turns out that the answer is -1 while I expected it to be 7. Is java broken?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let us walk through the order of execution:

1. Before `new d()` creates an object of `d`, it needs to invoke `super()`.
2. Control is transferred to the default constructor of `b`.
3. Constructor of class `b` will invoke the method `b` but since there is an overridden method available in class `d`, it will be invoked.
4. Note that the instance of `b` is not yet created and the value of `i` is hidden (`d.i` hides `b.i`) and hence the value of `i` is `0`. So doing `--i` generates `-1` as the output.

Comment: This is far superior to some of the dupes maybe you can consider also answering some of them in the same manner